# Finger Alpha Masking Libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, blending

I have two textures which one is above the other. When user drags finger on the screen I get the path of the finger and I can draw any colour I want above the two textures following the finger path and drawing GL Triangles.

However, rather than drawing I want to change the alpha value of the above texture to 0 where the finger path is, so the below texture will be shown (where the finger path is). Is this possible to be done with Libgdx because I can't find how. If not, do you have any other suggestions how can this be implemented?

This is more or less how a paint eraser would work.

Thanks

Comment: you want this to happen with geometry?  or are you already putting your path on the upper texture as pixels?

Comment: I'm constructing a polygon on the fly by expanding the path pixels to both sides. Basically I set the vertices around that polygon and by usinf triangles i draw the expanded path.  Do you have any idea how I could get all pixels inside that polygon maybe it would be a good idea.

Comment: Check out libgdx alpha masking.